# Manipular uma janela aberta a partir da janela pai com Javascript

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet

Estou pensando em utilizar o recurso nativo `window.open()` para criar um pequeno sistema web que seja similar a sistemas desktop (feitos com o windows forms). Meu problema é em relação a comunicação e manipulação de dados/eventos entre 2 janelas.

Preciso saber como posso manipular janelas instanciadas a partir de uma janela pai, atualizando seu DOM, executando funções, etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma maneira de se manipular a `window` do `window.open()` é guardando a sua declaração em uma variável. Por exemplo:

```
var win = window.open("pagina.html", "", "width=400, height=400");
```

No exemplo acima, irá abrir a `pagina.html` com uma largura e uma altura de 400px.

Os argumentos são, respectivamente: `origem`, `windowName` e `atributos`.

---

Você também pode abrir uma janela vazia e inserir dados manualmente, porém isso é bastante limitado. Você faria isso basicamente com o `document.write()`, da seguinte maneira.

```
win.document.write(seu html);
win.document.write("<img src='img.jpg' alt='' />"); // por exemplo
```

Você não pode usar o `.innerHTML` já que não possui HTML ainda.

---

Uma outra técnica é esta:

```
var popup = window.open("", "popup", "width=400, height=400");
popup.document.write("<html><head><title>Exemplo</title></head><body>");
// Captura a div#content e insere seu conteudo HTML na popup
popup.document.write(document.getElementById('content').innerHTML);

popup.document.write("</body></html>");
```

E que você insere na *window* um conteúdo já existente algum local de seu site.

---

Para manipular os elementos você pode usar JQuery, assim:

```
var body = $("body", popup.document); // especifica-se o documento como segundo argumento.
```

Pode inserir elementos:

```
body.append('<input type="text"/>')
```

E por aí vai...

---

Aqui vai um exemplo de funções:

```
var popup = window.open("", "popup", "width=200, height=100");
popup.document.write("<html><head><title></title></head><body></body></html>");

var body = $("body", popup.document);
body.append('<input type="text" id="texto"> <br> <span><span>');

var text = body.children('input:text');
var span = body.children('span');
text.keyup(function() {
  span.text(text.val())
})
```

---

Um modo de manipular os elementos da *popup*, sendo que estes elementos são pertencentes a uma outra página, é usar o `.load()` do jquery, fiz testes com o `.ready()`, mas não obtive sucesso. Ficaria algo como isto:

```
var popup = window.open("exemplo.html", "popup", "width=200, height=100");
// No load declara-se a popup
$(popup).load(function(){
    var body = $('body', popup.document); //seleciona o body com a declaração do documento da popup
    body.css('background', '#333');
})
```

Assim, você ficaria livre para configurar os elementos já criados em outra página.

Obs.: A manipulação do DOM em uma popup não funciona no Chrome no protocolo `file`. Já no protocolo `http` funciona normalmente, assim como no Firefox.

Espero que tenha ajudado...

Comment: Acho que já responde até a [outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107619/4808) que ele fez.